# Sort a list of tuples by their second element and absolute value

Tags: sorting, haskell, tuples

How to sort this list

```
[("apple",3),("apple",-2),("pear",1)]
```

by the second element in the tuple, and by absolute value, so

```
[("pear",1),("apple",-2),("apple",3)]
```

Comment: `sortWith f == sortBy (comparing f) == sortBy (compare `on` f)`. they're all just exactly the same, one thing. something *substantial* though that could be further discussed is the [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) pattern.

Comment: @WillNess Is my other answer in the direction that you pointed towards with your comment?

Comment: @Boris that sort of thing is usually needed with a *costly* "key" (i.e. "to-sort-by") function; here it's not needed, as only `abs` is recalculated multiple times, and it's cheap. your second function is close, but instead of `sort` it's better to use `sortBy (comparing fst3) ... where fst3(a,_,_)=a`, to eliminate any influence of other fields on sorting (for duplicate keys). Also, instead of having to use `fst3`, usually you'd arrange the data in a nested fashion, so plain `fst` could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a paraphrased approach:

```
import Data.List
import GHC.Exts

sortWith (abs . snd) [("apple",3),("apple",-2),("pear",1)]
```

You can apply it to any problem requiring *Sort a **container** by **transformed keys***.

In your case `abs . snd` function is used for transforming `("Foo", -5)` to `5` and then sorted by new keys.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (sortBy)

sortBy (comparing (\(x,y) -> abs y)) [("apple",3),("apple",-2),("pear",1)]
```

This is the first thing I have written in Haskell so I wouldn't mind if someone pointed out why this is wrong and how to improve it.

After the comment by @WillNess on the original question, here is a version that attempts to use the "decorate-sort-undecorate" pattern:

```
[ (a,b) | (foo,a,b) <- sort [ (abs b,a,b) | (a,b) <- x ] ]
```

Where x is the original list.

Comment: Unless you want to go point-free like @jamshidh's answer, the only think I'd change is to remove the parentheses around `y`.

Comment: To clarify the "point-free" comment, you could instead write `comparing (abs . snd)` or `comparing $ abs . snd`. But I agree, your code is great.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman Yes, I sort of got what the "point-free" means, after some googling. I don't have a feeling, however, why the one version should be preferred over the other: concerning "idiomatic" code, readability, use-case, etc. This is something I am trying to figure out for myself anyway.

Comment: It's really just a matter of taste, and tastes on this actually differ quite a bit. What you wrote is perfectly valid, idiomatic Haskell code imo.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Data.Function
import Data.List

sortBy (compare `on` abs . snd) [("apple",3),("apple",-2),("pear",1)]
```